# Execute command using `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell` and yield lines of stdout, stderr and finally the return code

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, child-process, grpc

My task is to run a subprocess using `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell` and yield the lines of output. I am using `asyncio` to avoid creating threads just to pump the streams.

- It is necessary to separate stdout lines from stderr lines.
- Both outputs need to be read simultaneously, it is not possible to read all of stdout or stderr first, because then the other output buffer in the subprocess may fill and it would stop running.
- This function is incorporated into a gRPC service, which is the reason for wrapping the yielded lines in instances of `cli_pb2.ExecuteReply(...)`
- `.readline()` returns "" on EOF, so when I see it, that is when to stop reading that stream.

I want to ask if my approach to reading stdout and stderr simultaneously can be improved. I was looking for something akin to UNIX select() and found `asyncio.wait({...}, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)`. Then I had to figure out which stream (stdout, stderr) the result corresponds to. I hacked at it by looking at `_coro`.

```py
import asyncio

import cli_pb2
import cli_pb2_grpc

async def run(cmd):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    stderr_readline = proc.stderr.readline()
    stdout_readline = proc.stdout.readline()
    pending = {stderr_readline, stdout_readline}

    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for f in done:
            line = (await f).decode()
            if f._coro is stderr_readline:  # bad, but it works and can't think of better approach
                if line:
                    yield cli_pb2.ExecuteReply(stderr=line)
                    stderr_readline = proc.stderr.readline()
                    pending.add(stderr_readline)  # put it back into the `pending` set
            if f._coro is stdout_readline:
                if line:
                    print(line)
                    yield cli_pb2.ExecuteReply(stdout=line)
                    stdout_readline = proc.stdout.readline()
                    pending.add(stdout_readline)
    await proc.wait()
    status = proc.returncode
    yield cli_pb2.ExecuteReply(status=status)
```

Usage example

```py
async def printlines():
    async for line in run("echo a; sleep 5; echo b; echo c"):
        print(line)
```

outputs (with a 5 second pause after first line

```
stdout: "a\n"
stdout: "b\n"
stdout: "c\n"
```

The protobuf definition is

````
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "djtests.cli";
option java_outer_classname = "CliProto";

package cli;

service Executor {
    rpc Execute (ExecuteRequest) returns (stream ExecuteReply) {
    };
}

message ExecuteRequest {
    string cmd = 1;
}

message ExecuteReply {
    oneof reply_fields {
        string stdout = 1;
        string stderr = 2;
        int32 status = 3;  // sent in the last message
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Example of a solution using threaded approach, which I wanted to avoid, is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/redirecting-subprocesses-output-stdout-and-stderr-to-the-logging-module

Comment: Advice on how to better associate the returned line with its source (stdout or stderr), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509586/how-to-know-which-coroutines-were-done-with-asyncio-wait